# Set pie chart to non touchable

Tags: mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I'm using this awesome plotter framework ios-charts. The documentation for the android version states that one can disable touch events on the charts with "setTouchEnabled(false). However I can't find this function in the iOS version. "touchesBegan" might the way to go here? I'm new to iOS programming so I'm not that familiar with touch events.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable user interaction via the attributes inspector or with

```
chartView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

[image]